# Uncommon function definition in the 'less' program source

Tags: c, function, syntax

My friend asked me could I add "frozen top line" feature to the standard **less** *NIX program. I started to view the source and was very surprised in function definition the **filename.c**:

```
public char *
last_component(name)
    char *name;
{
    ....
}
```

I wrote some code at the C and usually I met:

- `return_type function_name arguments_list;` if it is function prototype
- `return_type function_name arguments_list code-block` if it is function definition.

But here I found something new: `return_type function_name arguments list` **something_mysterious**; `code block`.

What does this syntax means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is old C syntax ([also known as K&R style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#K.26R_style)), where a function definition could be written as where the argument are declared on the subsequent line:

```
int func(a,b)
   int a;
   char b;
{
```

Comment: A function definition *still can* be written that way.  It's still in the standard.  Also, it is *not* just the same as the corresponding signature with a parameter-type list: the K&R-style definition does not provide a prototype, and if there isn't a prototype in scope at the point of call (which can be provided separately), then that has practical implications for how arguments are interpreted.

Comment: Emphasizing what John Bollinger has said, these are **not** “just the same.” When a function declared only with the K&R style is called, the default argument promotions will be applied. When a function declared with the modern style (a *prototype*) is called, the default argument promotions will not be applied (except for arguments corresponding to `...`), and the arguments will be converted to the types of the parameters as if by assignment. *E.g.*, with a prototype, you can pass `float` for an `int` argument or vice-versa. Without a prototype, the behavior is then undefined.

Comment: @eric and John, What I meant to infer was they were similar from syntax point of view, I've updated to reflect that part.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK, I agree. I would have expanded on the prototype part, but since it's already duped, I'll remove the incorrect part.